# Modified Airy differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Trying to solve the following differential equation:

$y''-kz*y=0$

where k is a constant, I found that the general solution was

$y(z)=C_1*A_i(z* \sqrt[3]{\xi} )+ C_2*B_i(z* \sqrt[3]{\xi} )$

on a online calculator without extra explanation. So I discovered the Airy function $A_i$ and $B_i$ but what are the $\xi$ functions ?

Comment: The $\xi$ should be $k$ and the Airy functions are **not** indexed by $i$ they are just $\mathrm{Ai}$ and $\mathrm{Bi}.$